# If I need to manually custom code from npm module, how should I do it

Tags: react-native, npm

In the react-native world I came across using many lib packages, some of them are outdated or not maintained. By going through the issue ticket or google for some solution to some bug, sometime I found a solution but how should I apply it?

I normally just change the code inside node_module directly, but I know this is really bad way cause it not even my git and gonna be lost at some point

what is the proper way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can install node modules that aren't in the registry. 
 See: https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/install

Specifically these two methods are worth a look.

```
npm install <git-host>:<git-user>/<repo-name>
npm install <git repo url>
```

If the module in question are hosted on github, clone the repository, apply the patch to it there, and then use the module directly from github.

You could also see if anyone else is maintaining a fork of it.